# My app won't run on my iPhone, because my iPhone is IOS version 12.1.2 while my xcode only supports up until 11.2

Tags: ios, xcode, device

Im trying to install my app on my iPhone. I am currently using a MacBook Air which, as far as im concerned, cannot run the newest version of Xcode. So Xcode inevitably gets the "could not locate device support files" error. Is there any way of adding the needed info in the /DeviceSupport folder to fix the issue? my original goal was to successfully download my own app onto my iPhone, so that it could be run, without being connected to my Mac (I am not enrolled in the developer program yet). But I figure if I can't even run the app on my Iphone as a simulator, then I have to start there.

Comment: If your really stuck you could post it to TestFlight, send yourself a link and download it on your phone. However that's the worst possible solution

Comment: well unless if someone could try and post their /DeviceSupport folder and maybe I could copy-paste it and see if that works

Comment: @NiallKehoe well to do that I would have to register with 99 dollars to get developer "pass" wouldn't I?

Comment: Ya You would, are you sure the download won't work? I'd probably try again on that

Comment: @NiallKehoe if u are asking that im sure testFlight does not work then no, because I haven't downloaded it just researched at found that u have to be enrolled. if u are running the latest version of xcode could you do me a solid and send me ur /DeviceSupport folder? If u dont know where to find it I'm happy to lead you through the process :)

Comment: I can send it to you. Send on instructions of where to get it and where to upload it.

Comment: @NiallKehoe thanks man I appreciate it! the location of the folder is here /Applications/Xcode10.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport. If u can i would like you to send it to my email at karlmogensen@hotmail.com

Comment: Okay I'll send it on.

Comment: Its uploaded now. Should I add an answer with the link to the files in it?

Comment: yes please add in comment section

Comment: Downloadable at: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/g5feicd2lrlqv83/AAC0qJJRdwGg_akBfedcJ_ZIa?dl=0

Comment: It works! thanks man I appreciate it! :D

Comment: add an answer and ill up vote you @NiallKehoe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can downloaded the Device Support code at this link: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/g5feicd2lrlqv83/AAC0qJJRdwGg_akBfedcJ_ZIa?dl=0 . Then replace the old one.